Can't change Z index with Mantine Pop over component styles
Summary
I'm trying to update the popover component styles in my Mantine project so that the z-index is 1 instead of 300, but I can't seem to make it work. The backgroundColor style works correctly, so it appears that the component is being accessed.
Here is my code:
import "@mantine/core/styles.css";
import { createTheme, MantineProvider, Popover } from "@mantine/core";
import PageRouter from "./PageRouter";

function App() {
    return (
        <MantineProvider theme={customTheme}>
            <PageRouter />
        </MantineProvider>
    );
}

export default App;

const customTheme = createTheme({
    fontFamily: "Nunito Sans, sans-serif",
    components: {
        Popover: Popover.extend({
            styles: {
                dropdown: {
                    zIndex: 1,
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                },
            },
        }),
    },
});



You seem to be correctly setting the styles of the popover, so I would have no solution to solve this in the theme file. But I do have workaround which could work:
In the documentation of mantine popover there is a zIndex prop (https://mantine.dev/core/popover/?t=props). You could create a custom component, which is using the popover of mantine, but you add the zIndex={1} as a prop. So if you reuse the component, its index is always 1.

Thank you I was aware that there was in index prop on the popover component. I was just hoping to using the theme as a way to manage all my indexes across my components so it is centralised.  But I did end up doing as per your suggestion as I could not find a way to change the Zindex through the theme.
Seems to be something you just can not do.
